# Giving SU Permissions to Android App via ADB

Tags: android, adb, root, instrumentation, su

I'm currently writing scripts for android that can grant SU permissions to certain test apps. I was wondering if anyone knows how to grant SU permissions to an app via the ADB command line?

Thanks!

EDIT: I see that this question is getting a lot of downvotes probably because of the nature of what I'm asking. Perhaps I should explain that I'm doing this to facilitate automation tests that require SU permissions on runtime and to avoid having to set up the SU permissions manually when connecting new devices to the automation hub.

Comment: Why would you want to do such thing?

Comment: The desire is that I'd like to grant SU permissions to my test devices at the start of the regression tests. Of course, I could set up SU manually prior to connecting the device but its just an extra step that we could possibly gloss over.

Comment: Why is this being down-voted?